# OpenCV -Visual Studio 2015

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2015

I'm working  OpenCv 2.4.11 version with Visual Studio 2015.When I try the sample code ,I'm getting  "the application was unable to start correctly 0xc00007b" error.My code is below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Mat img = imread("C:/Users/Murat/Desktop/lena1.png");

    if (img.empty()) {
        cout << "Resim yüklenemedi" << endl;
        return -1;

    }
    namedWindow("deneme penecere ismi", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("deneme penecere ismi", img);
    waitKey(0);
    destroyWindow("deneme penecere ismi");


    return  0;
}
```

How can I fix problem.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct DLL's version for your Windows? `OpenCV x64 = Windows x64`

Comment: Did you recompiled opencv with vs 2015 compiler? Last time I checked, , it was pre-built only for 2012 and 2013

Comment: Yes,I compiled succesfully.@Miki and @Berriel DLL's version is correct

Comment: Did you copied dll in exe folder? Or added dll folder to PATH?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Build OpenCV with the Visual Studio 2015 compiler from source first. This reduces the risk that older frameworks are missing from your computer. You need the vc14 directory as a source of your libs. Prebuilt libs are only for VS 2012 and 2013, which are the VC11 and VC12 libs folders under your opencv/build/x64 or x86.

Steps are simple.

1. Download CMAKE, install.
2. Download source code of Opencv, extract.
3. Run Cmake and add the directory of your source and target directory for your project.
4. Configure Cmake, choosing the right compiler, VS2015, first. There are many options. Just try the default one first.
5. Run Cmake. Result is Visual Studio 2015 project like opencv.sln under target directory.
6. Open opencv.sln project.
7. Build this project with Visual Studio 2015.

Result is VC14 directory with libs to include.

Check this picture by picture tutorial. [Tutorial Here](http://funvision.blogspot.com/2015/11/install-opencv-visual-studio-2015.html)

Comment: Its surprice me every time how often I could ## about OpenCV because some stuff is missing and I always ends up with CMAKE... Thx for short tutorial and link.

Answer (score 1):

Configuration steps:

1-Add dlls in bin directory to the system path.

2-Add include directory to the project properties -> VC++ directories -> include

3-Add '.lib' files in lib directory to the project properties -> Linker -> Additional Dependencies

[Explanatory Link](http://keepinsoft.com/opencv-249-visual-studio-2013-konfigurasyon-ayarlari/)